# Return JWT token when user signs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, jwt

Having an issue with getting JWT token using `devise gem` and `devise-jwt gem`. This is how my confirmation looks like.

**devise.rb**

```
  Devise.setup do |config|

    config.jwt do |jwt|
      jwt.secret =  SECRETS.devise_jwt_secret_key
      jwt.dispatch_requests = [ ['POST', %r{^/authentication_tokens/create$}] ]
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
           :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Null

  end
```

**authentication_tokens_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::AuthenticationTokensController < Devise::SessionsController
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token 

  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:create]

  before_action :rewrite_param_names, only: [:create]

  def new
    render json: { response: "Authentication required" }, status: 401
  end

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
     render json: {success: true, jwt: current_token, response: "Authentication successful" }
  end

  private

  def rewrite_param_names
    request.params[:user] = {email: request.params[:email], password: request.params[:password]}
  end

  def current_token
    request.env['warden-jwt_auth.token']
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
   get 'home#secret'
   devise_for :users
   resources :tasks
   #other routes for the website removed for brevity

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
      devise_scope :user do
        post '/authentication_tokens/create', to: "authentication_tokens#create"
      end
    end
  end
```

For some reason `request.env['warden-jwt_auth.token']` returns `null` all the time, however, the user is authenticated.
Is there anything that I need to add to get the JWT token when a user signs in?

**Update - routes and namespacing**

After days of debugging, I believe I have found the source of my problem.  My app has a frontend which uses normal routes. The code above doesn't work however if I do something like the code below. All is good.

```
  scope :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'v1/authentication_tokens'}
  end
```

Is there a way of namespacing the `devise_for` for me API even though it has been used above for the website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to make your route RESTful.

**routes.rb**

```
post '/authentication_tokens', to: "authentication_tokens#create"
```

**devise.rb**

```
config.jwt do |jwt|
  jwt.secret =  SECRETS.devise_jwt_secret_key
  jwt.dispatch_requests = [ ['POST', %r{^/authentication_tokens$}] ]
end
```

Comment: @Benjamin is there anything that you didn’t mentioned in your example? I’ve reproduced issue with your example and fixed it by this way.

Comment: after debugging further I realise that the problem is actually with the routes. Please see my update.

Comment: This answer saved me after days of debugging! When you are, like OP, having 2 different entry points for your users to authenticate on. For example an admin/sign_in route with a form and an api/v1/login endpoint which accepts json this answer tells the JWT gem on which urls to append the authorisation header. Brilliant thanks!

Comment: super clean, should be flag as actual answer..!

Answer (score 5):

I've briefly looked on your issue and, it's probably wrong, but something for you to give a try:

looking on the following lines

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
end

def current_token
  request.env['warden-jwt_auth.token']
end
```

If you say that user is being authenticated even with `nil` returned from `current_token` method, so that means that jwt is passing correctly, but your way of fetching it is wrong.

Try to debug `self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)` line and see what contains inside `auth_options`, probably you can take JWT from there, or you just trying to get `warden-jwt_auth.token` in a wrong way. Try to debug this line as well and see if you should probably take "warden-jwt_auth.token" from `request.headers["warden-jwt_auth.token"]`, or something like this. Just print out the whole response of your request and search by needed header.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

update `jwt.dispatch_requests` with full path, after that restart rails, is working for me.

**devise.rb**

```html
config.jwt do |jwt|
  jwt.secret = "secret"
  jwt.dispatch_requests = [ ['POST', %r{^/api/v1/authentication_tokens/create$}] ]
  jwt.expiration_time = 1.day.to_i
end
```

Comment: The problem was the routes.